# Schedule running executable using powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need to write a script, which will create task scheduler job, which at pc startup will run executable. In short, script will be something like this:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:10
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -Name FileJob -ScriptBlock {$args[0]}
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following Powershell snippet to create Windows Scheduled Tasks.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'application.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden'
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:10
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "FileJob" -Description "FileJob"
```

Comment: It looks like it's correct, thanks, man. But it doesn't start my application (I tried to use instead of 'application.exe' string 'C:\Windows\notepad.exe', but it also doesn't work)

Comment: Just exclude the arguments ..  (I used this to set up hidden processes to run in the background. e.g.
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'notepad.exe'

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to create my task:

```
#The first command uses the New-ScheduledTaskAction cmdlet to assign the action variable $A to the executable file tskmgr.exe
$A = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "C:\directory\powershell.ps1"

#The second command uses the New-ScheduledTaskTrigger cmdlet to assign the trigger variable $T to the value AtLogon
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -weekly -DaysOfWeek Saturday -At 7am

#The third command uses the New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet cmdlet to assign the settings variable $S to a task settings object
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -DontStopOnIdleEnd -ExecutionTimeLimit 1:00:00 -MultipleInstances 2

#The fourth command assigns the principal variable to the New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal of the scheduled task, Domain\Username
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId domain\gMSAaccount$ -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest

#The fifth command sets the description varible to $D for the task definition
$D = "Insert your description here"

#Registers the new scheduled task and defines it by using the $D variable
Register-ScheduledTask Name_of_Task -Action $A -Trigger $T -Settings $S -Principal $P -Description $D<p>
```

I found that using gMSA accounts are the best in an active directory environment. [Implement gMSA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/)
 The requirement is that in order to use gMSA, you must create your task with a powershell script or schtask.exe.